# Get the recent date from three columns in excel file

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc, excel

I have an excel file that has three columns:

```
Par1 - Post2    - Prep3

null - 20120615 - 20120616
```

I want to save the recent date in the status_date (which is in the prep3).

```
status_date

20130616
```

I tried the code below for par1, post2 and prep3 but it saves three rows of data on my DB, first row is for null, second row is for 20120615 and third row is 20120616. I only want to save the third row w/c has the recent date and not the other rows. How can I do that?

```
ExcelData data = new ExcelData();

//Status No
        data.status_no = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["status_no"].ToString();

//Par1
        data.par1 = ConvertDateTime(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["par1"].ToString());

using(var trans = DB.db.GetTransaction()) {
    if (data.par1 != null) {
        id = Convert.ToInt32(DB.db.Insert("dbo.status_table", "id", new {
            status_date = data.par1, // data.post2 for post2 column & data.prep3 for prep3 column
            status_no = data.status_no,
            description = data.description,
        }));
    }
    trans.Complete();
}
```

Comment: Hi @Chris do you know how to do this?

Comment: Where's Excel in all of this? I don't see you doing anything with Excel.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is a horrible idea to use Office Interop from ASP.NET or another server technology. These APIs were written for use in a desktop application, for automating Office (a suite of desktop applications). Server applications are different in many ways that make it a very, very bad idea to use Office Interop in them. It's also unsupported by Microsoft, and may violate your Office license. See [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)